# clearTimeout() not working

Tags: javascript, object, syntax, literals

In the following code the clearTimeout() function doesn't seem to clear the timer. Please note: I've stripped the code down a bit to show the relevent parts. Any ideas?

```
var Gallery =
{

   next: function()
   {
   // does stuff
   },      

   close: function()
   {
   Gallery.slideshow("off");
   },

   slideshow: function(sw)
   {
   if (sw == "off") {clearTimeout(timer);}

   var timer = setTimeout(function() {Gallery.next();Gallery.slideshow();}, 1000);
   },
};
```

FULL CODE:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Gallery</title>

<meta name="description" content=" ">
<meta name="author" content=" ">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/css.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script>

var Gallery =
{

// PARAMETERS FOR CUSTOMISATION

gallery_type: "overlay",    // overlay(default), inpage, slideshow
transition_speed: 1000,     // milliseconds
outer_opacity: 0.7,         // 0 to 1 (option available with overlay)
outer_colour: "#000000",    // hex value
image_size: "800px",
show_captions: true,        // true, false
overlay_slideshow: true,   // true, false (option available with overlay)
slideshow_interval: 5000,   // milliseconds
slideshow_controls: false,  // true, false
fullscreen: false,          // true, false (option available with inpage)



thumbs: [],
images: [],
captions: [],
current_image_id: null,
timer: null,



   init: function()
   {

   // CREATE ARRAYS

   var gallery_div = document.getElementById("gallery");
   gallery_thumbs = gallery_div.getElementsByTagName("img");


   for (var i=0; i < gallery_thumbs.length; i++)
   {
   Gallery.thumbs[i] = gallery_thumbs[i];
   Gallery.thumbs[i].rel = [i];
   }

   for (var i=0; i < gallery_thumbs.length; i++)
   {
   Gallery.captions[i] = Gallery.thumbs[i].alt;
   }


   // CREATE OVERLAYS

   var body_tag = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
   var outer_overlay = document.createElement("div");
   outer_overlay.id = "outer";
   outer_overlay.style.backgroundColor = Gallery.outer_colour;
   var window_height =  $(document).height();
   outer_overlay.style.height = window_height +'px';
   body_tag[0].appendChild(outer_overlay);
   var inner_overlay = document.createElement("div");
   inner_overlay.id = "inner";
   body_tag[0].appendChild(inner_overlay);
   var close_button = document.createElement("img");
   close_button.src="images/icon-close.png";
   close_button.id = "gallery-close";
   inner_overlay.appendChild(close_button);
   var next_button = document.createElement("img");
   next_button.src="images/icon-next.png";
   next_button.id = "gallery-next";
   inner_overlay.appendChild(next_button);
   var prev_button = document.createElement("img");
   prev_button.src="images/icon-prev.png";
   prev_button.id = "gallery-prev";
   inner_overlay.appendChild(prev_button);
   var caption_div = document.createElement("div");
   caption_div.id = "gallery-caption";
   inner_overlay.appendChild(caption_div);

   $("#gallery-caption").fadeTo(0, 0);
   if (Gallery.show_captions == true) {
   inner_overlay.onmouseover = function() {$("#gallery-caption").stop().fadeTo(Gallery.transition_speed/2, 0.5);};
   inner_overlay.onmouseout = function() {$("#gallery-caption").stop().fadeTo(Gallery.transition_speed, 0);};
   }

   // CREATE IMAGES

   for (var i=0; i < Gallery.thumbs.length; i++)
   {
   var new_image = document.createElement("img");
   new_image.src = Gallery.thumbs[i].parentNode.href;
   new_image.id= "gallery-img" + (i + 1);
   inner_overlay.appendChild(new_image);
   Gallery.images[i] = new_image;
   $(Gallery.images[i]).fadeTo(0, 0);
   }


   // EVENT HANDLERS FOR OPEN AND CLOSE

   for (var i=0; i < Gallery.thumbs.length; i++)
   {
   Gallery.thumbs[i].onclick = Gallery.open;
   }

   var outer_overlay = document.getElementById("outer");
   outer_overlay.onclick = Gallery.close;
   close_button.onclick = Gallery.close;
   next_button.onclick = Gallery.next;
   prev_button.onclick = Gallery.previous;

   },



   open: function()
   {


   Gallery.current_image_id = this.rel;
   var current = Gallery.images[Gallery.current_image_id];
   var caption_div = document.getElementById("gallery-caption");
   caption_div.innerHTML = Gallery.captions[Gallery.current_image_id];


   var inner_overlay = document.getElementById("inner");
   inner_overlay.style.height = current.height + "px";

   // CENTER BUTTONS & OVERLAY
   var next_button = document.getElementById("gallery-next");
   next_button.style.top = (current.height / 2) -15 + "px";
   var prev_button = document.getElementById("gallery-prev");
   prev_button.style.top = (current.height / 2) -15 + "px";
   $("#inner").css("top", (($(window).height()-$("#inner").height())/2));
   $("#inner").css("left", (($(window).width()-$("#inner").width())/2));


   $(current).fadeTo(0, 1);
   $("#outer").fadeTo(0, Gallery.outer_opacity);
   $("#inner").fadeTo(0, 0);
   $("#inner").fadeTo(Gallery.transition_speed, 1);

   if (Gallery.overlay_slideshow == true) {
   Gallery.slideshow();
   }


   return false;

   },



   close: function()
   {

if (Gallery.timer) {
            clearInterval(Gallery.timer);
            Gallery.timer = null;
        } else {

   $("#outer").fadeTo(0, 0);
   $("#inner").fadeTo(0, 0);
   $("#outer").css("display", "none");
   $("#inner").css("display", "none");

   var current = Gallery.images[Gallery.current_image_id];
   current.style.display = "none";

   }

   },



   next: function()
   {

   var next_id = Number(Gallery.current_image_id) + 1;
   if (next_id == Gallery.images.length) {next_id = 0;}
   var next = Gallery.images[next_id];
   var current = Gallery.images[Gallery.current_image_id];

   var inner_overlay = document.getElementById("inner");
   inner_overlay.style.height = next.height + "px";

   // CENTER BUTTONS & OVERLAY
   var next_button = document.getElementById("gallery-next");
   next_button.style.top = (next.height / 2) -15 + "px";
   var prev_button = document.getElementById("gallery-prev");
   prev_button.style.top = (next.height / 2) -15 + "px";
   $("#inner").css("top", (($(window).height()-$("#inner").height())/2));
   $("#inner").css("left", (($(window).width()-$("#inner").width())/2));


   var caption_div = document.getElementById("gallery-caption");
   caption_div.innerHTML = Gallery.captions[next_id];


   $(current).fadeTo(Gallery.transition_speed, 0);
   $(next).fadeTo(0, 0);
   $(next).fadeTo(Gallery.transition_speed, 1);

   Gallery.current_image_id = next_id;

   },


   previous: function()
   {
   var prev_id = Number(Gallery.current_image_id) - 1;
   if (prev_id == -1) {prev_id = Gallery.images.length -1;}
   var prev = Gallery.images[prev_id];
   var current = Gallery.images[Gallery.current_image_id];

   var inner_overlay = document.getElementById("inner");
   inner_overlay.style.height = prev.height + "px";

   // CENTER BUTTONS & OVERLAY
   var next_button = document.getElementById("gallery-next");
   next_button.style.top = (prev.height / 2) -15 + "px";
   var prev_button = document.getElementById("gallery-prev");
   prev_button.style.top = (prev.height / 2) -15 + "px";
   $("#inner").css("top", (($(window).height()-$("#inner").height())/2));
   $("#inner").css("left", (($(window).width()-$("#inner").width())/2));


   var caption_div = document.getElementById("gallery-caption");
   caption_div.innerHTML = Gallery.captions[prev_id];


   $(current).fadeTo(Gallery.transition_speed, 0);
   $(prev).fadeTo(0, 0);
   $(prev).fadeTo(Gallery.transition_speed, 1);

   Gallery.current_image_id = prev_id;
   },



   slideshow: function() {
        Gallery.close();
        Gallery.timer = setInterval(function() {
            Gallery.next();
        }, 1000);
    },





   fullscreen: function()
   {

   }




};


// START SCRIPTS

Start = function()
{
Gallery.init();
};

window.onload = Start;



</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="gallery">
    <a href="images/argentina-river.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/argentina-river-thumb.jpg" alt="Argentina River"></a>
    <a href="images/monte-bre.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/monte-bre-thumb.jpg" alt="Monte Bre"></a>
    <a href="images/romania.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/romania-thumb.jpg" alt="Romania"></a>
    <a href="images/norway.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/norway-thumb.jpg" alt="Norway"></a>
    <a href="images/cloudy-skies.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/cloudy-skies-thumb.jpg" alt="Cloudy Skies"></a>
    <a href="images/field.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/field-thumb.jpg" alt="Field"></a>
    <a href="images/poland.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/poland-thumb.jpg" alt="Poland"></a>
    <a href="images/coconut-trees.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/coconut-trees-thumb.jpg" alt="Coconut Trees"></a>
    <a href="images/volcanic-land.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/volcanic-land-thumb.jpg" alt="Volcanic Land"></a>
    <a href="images/tokyo-city.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/tokyo-city-thumb.jpg" alt="Tokyo City"></a>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 11):

The `clearTimeout` is working, but you are immediately re-setting it in the same method. So it starts up again right away. You need to conditionally check for whether to start it:

```
slideshow: function(sw) {
    var timer;

    if (sw == "off") {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    } else {
        timer = setTimeout(function() { Gallery.next(); }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks - that's a good point, however even using the if else statement doesn't seem to clear it for some reason

Comment: this is because you are calling `Gallery.slideshow();` unnecessarily inside the timer callback. the whole approach is a little mangled. i'll post a new answer explaining in a minute.

Answer (score 4):

The way you structured your code is more complex than it needs to be and has a few bugs. I'd recommend restructuring it like this:

```
var Gallery = {
    timer: null,

    next: function() {
        /* do stuff */
    },

    close: function() {
        if (Gallery.timer) {
            clearInterval(Gallery.timer);
            Gallery.timer = null;
        }
    },

    slideshow: function() {
        Gallery.close();
        Gallery.timer = setInterval(function() {
            Gallery.next();
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

You'd start the slideshow with `Gallery.slideshow();` and stop it with `Gallery.close();`

Comment: Thanks Ben, I shall try this out :-)

Comment: This approach seems to break other parts of the script. Also unless I'm missing something there's nothing to recall the slideshow function so that it repeats.

Comment: @Chris, I'm sorry. I was confusing `setTimeout` with `setInterval`. I've updated my code to fix this. That's what makes it repeat.

Comment: @Chris, as for it making other parts of your code break, I don't know what to say. This is a cleaner approach than the one you were taking.

Comment: I should probably have included all the code originally and given more detail about what I am trying to achieve, I was just trying to keep it as brief as possible. I've added th efullcode now, if you want to take a look...if not no probs I understand :-) thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

that would be because you are re-setting the timeout after you have cleared it. Rethink the order of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call the slideshow function, the setTimeout gets executed indipendently of the sw variable being "off" or not.

```
slideshow: function(sw)
   {
   if (sw == "off") {
      clearTimeout(timer);
   } else {
      var timer = setTimeout(function() {Gallery.next();Gallery.slideshow();}, 1000);
   }
```